# Python LinkedList deletion method not working

Tags: python

This is my node:

```
class Node(object):
    def __init__(self, data, next = None):
      self.data = data
      self.next_node = next

    def get_next(self):
      return self.next_node

    def set_next(self, next):
      self.next_node = next

    def get_data(self):
      return self.data

    def set_data(self):
      self.data = data
```

And this is the LinkedList itself:

```
class LinkedList(object):
    def __init__(self, root = None):
      self.root = root
      self.size = 0

    def size(self):
      return self.size

    def insert(self, data):
      new_node = Node (data, self.root)
      self.root = new_node
      self.size += 1

    def delete(self, data):
      this_node = self.root
      prev_node = None
      while this_node:
        if this_node.get_data() == data:
          if prev_node:
            prev_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())
          else:
            self.root = this_node
          self.size -= 1
          return True
        else:
          prev_node = this_node
          this_node = this_node.get_next()
      return False

    def search(self, data):
      this_node = self.root
      while this_node:
        if this_node.get_data() == data:
          return data
        else:
          self.root = this_node.get_next()
        return None

    def printLL(self):
      this_node = self.root
      while this_node:
        print(this_node.data)
        this_node  = this_node.get_next()
```

Finally, these are the tests I'm performing:

```
ll = LinkedList()
ll.insert(1)
ll.insert(2)
ll.printLL()
ll.delete(2)
ll.printLL()
if ll.search(2):
    print("Value 2 found")
else:
    print("Value 2 not found")
if ll.search(1):
    print("Value 1 found")
else:
    print("Value 1 not found")
ll.insert(4)
ll.printLL()
print(str(ll.size))
```

I am currently getting this output:

```
2
1
2
1
Value 2 found
Value 1 not found
4
1
2
```

But I SHOULD be getting this output:

```
2 1
1
Value 2 not found
Value 1 found
4 1
2
```

2 should be deleted and the LinkedList should all appear on one line. Any idea why the deletion function isn't working? Also how could I properly format this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your error in deleting is here:

```
if prev_node:
  prev_node.set_next(this_node.get_next())
else:
  self.root = this_node
```

For the node with value `2`, there is no `prev_node` (it's at the head of the link), so you assign *the node itself* to `self.root`. You should assign the next node instead:

```
  self.root = this_node.get_next()
```

Next, your search code modifies your linked list; it assigns the first node to `self.root`, and then *always* return `None` immediately when no match is found on that first node:

```
while this_node:
  if this_node.get_data() == data:
    return data
  else:
    self.root = this_node.get_next()
  return None
```

Don't do that! You want `this_node` to be replaced instead, and only return `None` after the `while` loop has completed:

```
while this_node:
  if this_node.get_data() == data:
    return data
  else:
    this_node = this_node.get_next()
return None
```

As for printing; you are using a `print()` call per node, so either tell it to put spaces between nodes, or collect all node values into a list before printing:

```
def printLL(self):
  this_node = self.root
  first = False
  while this_node:
    print(' ' if not first else '', this_node.data, sep='', end='')
    first = False
    this_node  = this_node.get_next()
  print()
```

or

```
def printLL(self):
  this_node = self.root
  values = []
  while this_node:
    values.append(this_node.data)
    this_node  = this_node.get_next()
  print(*values)
```

Note that there is little point in giving `Node` getters and setters; just access the `next` and `data` attributes directly, like you already do in some places.

Together, with these changes the output becomes:

```
2 1
1
Value 2 not found
Value 1 found
4 1
2
```